# Is there an r function that would help me find the number of rows which carry data from a particular year?

Tags: r, date, count, record

I am completely new to R. Here is how my data looks like:

```
incident_id  date
1   461105  2013-01-01      
2   460726  2013-01-01      
3   478855  2013-01-01      
4   478925  2013-01-05      
5   478959  2013-01-07      
6   478948  2013-01-07      
7   479363  2013-01-19      
8   479374  2013-01-21      
9   479389  2013-01-21      
10  492151  2013-01-23
```

I would like to find out the number of times an incident has been reported in a given year.

The tail looks like this:

```
    incident_id      date
239668  1082234 2018-03-31      
239669  1081742 2018-03-31      
239670  1082990 2018-03-31      
239671  1081752 2018-03-31      
239672  1082061 2018-03-31      
239673  1083142 2018-03-31      
239674  1083139 2018-03-31      
239675  1083151 2018-03-31      
239676  1082514 2018-03-31      
239677  1081940 2018-03-31
```

I have tried SQL, but I would want to use R for this.

Code to find out incidents reported each year
First creating a subset with only data and incident ID

```
dfgvdates = dfgv[,1:2]

head(dfgvdates, 10)
```

I would like to use the `count()` function but I guess it can only be used if I use a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the year from the date and then count the length. Using `aggregate` we could do

```
aggregate(incident_id~date, transform(df, date = format(as.Date(date),"%Y")),length)
```

Or with `table`

```
stack(table(format(as.Date(df$date), "%Y")))
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we could do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(date = format(as.Date(date), "%Y")) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

Or using `count`

```
df %>% count(date = format(as.Date(date), "%Y"))
```

Comment: ! Did that. This was my first time using Stack Overflow and I am glad that I did that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT([, .(N = .N), by = .(Year = year(as.IDate(date)))]
```